# Share Clipboard between two PCs over Network

Tags: networking, command-line, server, windows, clipboard

I have the following setup:

A Windows computer on my left screen, connected to the local network.
A Raspberry Pi with Ubuntu Server 22.04 on the right screen, also connected to the local network

I want to share the clipboard between them (meaning, when I copy something on my windows device, it should send it to the clipboard of the Pi and the other way around).

Seems like a fairly easy task, however, I only found GUI Tools and VM solutions. Would it be hard to implement this myself? What are the alternatives, do you have any suggestions?

Comment: what clipboard on the PI. Servers do not have clipboards. Plus....if you copy text on windows/linux you can already paste it to linux/windows if you have an ssh connection. A tool like putty for instance can do this: putty is a tool to create a terminal session from windows.